# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "questions" is of type character varying[] but default expression is of type integer

Tags: python, django, postgresql

This is my model:

```
class college(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='college_image/',default=None)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    add_field = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, validators=[RegexValidator(r'^[789]\d{9}$')])
    status = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    last_date = models.DateTimeField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    reg_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True)
    questions = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=500),blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

An error occurred when I added a `questions` field in the model and used command 'python manage.py migrate', and the following hint was shown:

> HINT: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression

What does it mean? What should I do?

Comment: What exactly you want to do ? You want to add multiple questions in college class ?

Comment: Yes, I want to add multiple questions (questions in a list) in college model.

Comment: you simply can add another model named Question and add that as manytomany field in College class

Comment: @Amir thank you for your suggestion. I've resolved the issue by droping questions column and adding it again. The main problem was the default value, which wasn't provided as an array field.

Comment: @AnshulTiwari can you please post how your code looks after the "fix"?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but hopefully this answer can help somebody else. I fixed this same error by doing the following:

1. Add default `list` to the ArrayField. E.g.

```
answers = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(default=list))
```

2. Delete migration files in `migrations` folder except `__init__.py`
3. `python manage.py make migrations`
4. `python manage.py migrate`

So the issue was that in one of the migrations, the field was trying to be set to default 0 (programming error) but even after I fixed it in the code, the old migration was affected and thus it kept failing.